# What is CHIM, and how does it relate to the ludonarrative aspects of the Elder Scrolls games?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls

In the spirit of the [joint SFF/Arqade topic challenge](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13440/joint-sff-arqade-topic-challenge-the-elder-scrolls-august-2021?cb=1) regarding the Elder Scrolls series, I figured that since I couldn't see any Elder Scrolls question, I'd start off by asking one of the more notoriously weird aspects of the Elder Scrolls' lore:

What is [CHIM](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/CHIM)? How does it relate to the relationship between the player, their in-game character, and ludonarrative elements like the use of save games, pause menus, modding tools, and other methods for customizing the way you might play the game?

Comment: https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/CHIM -

Comment: I've read this question a few times and I really don't understand what you're asking or what a decent answer might look like.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not so certain what's confusing you, since I thought I was being fairly straight-forward. I'm asking a question I already basically know the answer to as part of the topic challenge, since the lore of the games is on-topic for this SE site. There's allusions to all the ludonarrative elements I mentioned in the 36 Lessons of Vivec, though it's possible that newer sources have added more.

Comment: @Valorum: IMHO this is a real question, if a bit broad. The real problem is that most of the serious lore buffs will basically answer it with some variation of "You're oversimplifying things, it's not just a fourth-wall break. It's more complicated than that!" Unfortunately, at that point I tend to lose interest, so I'm not sure where the answer goes from there.

Comment: It seems you're very much begging the question here. You've decided that saving the game is explained in-Universe by the PC's use of CHIM, then asking how that is related. And using the word "ludonarrative" to sound smart, though it's meaningless in context.

Comment: @OrangeDog The term "ludonarrative" is used to describe the intersection between gameplay mechanics and the narrative. Chim comes up in the narrative of TES3, and describes gamey elements in in-universe terms. It's neither subtle (assuming you read those lines at all) nor particularly impactful, but it seems like a straightforward example of a "ludonarrative" element to me. In this case, it aligns the in-universe chosen one with the game's focus around the player.

Comment: @Harabeck the word "ludonarrative" was coined as "ludo-narrative dissonance" (by someone trying to sound smart) in order to contrast the gameplay (e.g. messing about with side-quests) and the narrative (e.g. the world is about to end). A "ludonarrative element" isn't a thing. It doesn't even apply to your examples, because saving, pausing, modding, etc. are not gameplay.

Comment: @OrangeDog If there can be ludonarrative dissonance, then there can be ludonarrative harmony. Describing an element of the game explicitly trying to create that harmony as a "ludonarrative" element seems pretty easy to understand. Your opinion of the motives of those who coined and use the term aside, I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: So, what's the answer? If you're looking for ESO, IDK; I don't pay $15 a month to play video games.